# Outputting information from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given an array section1, it contains 2 objects title and content, help me output data from these 2 objects into dynamically created <div class="card"

```
 {type: 'main', section1: [
                        {title: 'title_one', content: 'cont_1'},
                        {title: 'title_two', content: 'cont_2'}
                        ]
}

function main (content) {
    const html = content.section1.map((item, index) => `<div class="card">  
                                                            <h1>${content.title[index]}</h1>
                                                        </div>`)
    return `
    <main>
        <section>${html.join('')}</section>
    </main>`
}
```

Comment: How are you calling main? What are you passing to it? `content` doesn't have `title` as a direct child.

Comment: In your mapping, `item` will be `{title: 'title_one', content: 'cont_1'}` and `{title: 'title_two', content: 'cont_2'}`, respectively in each iteration. So perhaps instead of `content.title[index]`, which makes no sense (title is a string and has no reference to the section1 array), you may want `item.title` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
content.title[index]
```

with

```
content.section1[index].title
```